# Mutex ApplicationException when using async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpclient, mutex

I am trying to get the response from a url, and when I use the `await` and `async` in my function, my `Mutex` throws an error.

Error output :

```
System.ApplicationException
Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
 at System.Threading.Mutex.ReleaseMutex()
```

Code :

```
private async void getData ()
{
    _mutex.WaitOne();

    try
    {
        string url = "https://urllink.com";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO
        throw e;
    }
           
    _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you need a mutex, here?

Comment: The mutex was implemented by a previous dev

Comment: Mhm. Why did he think you need a mutex here?

Comment: @Fildor not sure either of those are relevant to the code, honestly; I can see uses for mutex here in terms of acting as a concurrency throttle

Comment: @MarcGravell That's why I am asking. I don't want to suggest throwing them out, if there's a good reason.

Comment: In terms of *code*, there *is* a problem here in that the mutex isn't released in the failure case; the "release" should be in a `finally` so that it happens either way (and a `catch` that just has `throw e;` is a `catch` you can remove); however... I'm not sure that would fail *in the way discussed*

Comment: @MarcGravell Could synchronization context play into that exception, OP is seeing?

Comment: You shouldn't use normal mutexes in async code. Async code using await can wander from thread to thread as await is handled, and mutexes have thread affinity, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/mutexes) for more information. When a different thread than the one owning the mutex tries to release it, an ApplicationException is thrown, as you've experienced.

Comment: @Fildor normally you would *expect* this to break in the way that it is; ironically (perhaps), there are scenarios where sync-context might *silently fix* this code - for example, in winforms / WPF the sync-context would shunt the code back to the UI thread (assuming it started on the UI thread), which means you're back on the correct thread by a fluke

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It is intended specifically for event handlers. To create asynchronous methods we use `async Task`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would propose <s>two</s> *three* changes here:

0. replace `async void` with `async Task` (credit: [Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor)), and make sure you `await` it
1. replace `Mutex` with `SemaphoreSlim` (a `new SemaphoreSlim(1,1)` is basically the same thing as a `Mutex`) - the `Mutex` documentation is heavily focused on "the thread that owns the mutex", which strongly suggests it is thread-bound, and `await` is incompatible with thread-bound scenarios; `SemaphoreSlim`, however, is *not* thread-bound; additionally, it has an async-aware `WaitAsync()` API, avoiding thread blocks (i.e. replace `_mutex.WaitOne();` with `await _semaphore.WaitAsync();`)
2. put the release in a `finally`, so that it is released even in the failure case

But "1" seems to be the real problem here. I would also speculate that this code worked fine until it was changed to `async`.

You could also remove the `catch`, as a `catch` that just has `throw` is redundant; a `catch` that just has `throw e;` is *worse* than redundant: it breaks the stack-trace.

Comment: Yes, the application exception is caused by the thread affinity of the mutex, a different thread tried to release the mutex than was currently owning it, this is explicitly not allowed.

Comment: Yes your speculation is indeed right that the code worked fine until I added async due to the await in client.GetStringAsync(url). The first change will be taken into consideration and second change was implemented but the issue still persists.

Comment: @Blacky_99 the first change is the thing that is needed - as confirmed by Lasse

Comment: You **cannot** use a Mutex in code that might transition to a different thread due to `await`. You **will** have this problem. You can keep most of the code mostly as-is, but you need to change to a synchronization object that doesn't have thread affinity. [AsyncEx by Stephen Cleary](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) has quite a few that can be used instead if you want the lock acquisition to be async as well. If that's not an issue you can switch to a SemaphoreSlim as Marc has described.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend against `async void` in favor of `async Task`. And reuse of an HttpClient instance instead of creating a new one on each call.

Comment: @Fildor great eyes - yeah, `async void` is very bad; added (with credit)

Comment: @Blacky_99 definitely that too ^^^^ - `async void`: nope every time

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen "If that's not an issue" - either way: `SemaphoreSlim` *has* async acquisition, at least in any runtime that I wouldn't run screaming from

Comment: Ah, OK, then I missed the async acquisition :)